# Using SignalR 2 in ASP.NET 5 application

Tags: asp.net, signalr

SignalR 3 and ASP.NET 5 were working together nicely up until the beta7 version. Now Microsoft states that SignalR 3 is 'on hold', and one should not expect the two to work together in the near future:

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/119

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues/121

So the question: is there a way to make at least SignalR 2 work in an ASP.NET 5 app?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the general solution for using owin-compatible middleware in this article:
https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/01/asp-net-vnext-middleware-versus-owinkatana-middleware/

1. Reference the `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin` package
2. Insert the following code into `Startup.Configure`:

```cs
app.UseOwin(addToPipeline =>
{
    addToPipeline(next =>
    {
        var appBuilder = new AppBuilder();
        appBuilder.Properties["builder.DefaultApp"] = next;

        appBuilder.MapSignalR();

        return appBuilder.Build<AppFunc>();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SignalR 2 also runs on .NET Core 2, when you poke around in the internals:

```
// SignalR checks if it's running in a Mono environment and then
// disables features like performance counters
// .NET Core isn't Mono, but doesn't have the performance counters DLL
// Let's make .NET Core a Mono
var signalRAssembly = typeof(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection).Assembly;
// This type is internal
var monoUtility = signalRAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.MonoUtility");
var field = monoUtility.GetField(
    "_isRunningMono",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
);
field.SetValue(null, new System.Lazy<bool>(() => true));
```