# Can I use the old SignalR package with Asp.Net Core if I target the full .Net framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I am writing an Asp.Net Core app using the full .Net framework. I would like to add SignalR support, but I see that SignalR for Asp.Net Core is not yet production ready.

Is it possible to use the old SignalR package in Asp.Net Core when I target the full .Net Framework?

Comment: Didn't tried yet, so no definite answer, but the old SingalR package uses Owin.While ASP.NET Core is remotely based on Owin/katana spec, its not used in the normal flow.Though there have been blog posts who successfully used the old owin based libraries with ASP.NET Cores middleware system. Second, SignalR like ASP.NET legacy,depend on System.Web (IIS/HttpSys specific library),while ASP.NET Core removed all references to System.Web. So it may or may not be possible. May I ask what feature are lacking in ASP.NET Core SignalR that you require the old one? Is the preview state your only concern?

Comment: No, but you'll can use the new signalr from the 2.1 previews.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. [See this answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921505/7747594).
I am migrating a web service to `Net Standard` (to be able to compile it for net core and net framework) and we need to keep `SignalR` compatibility with old clients on the net framework compilation. That is why I need to use `SignalR` (not core) on `ASP.NET Core`.